# Java - Oracle UCM invalid field at CHECKIN_UNIVERSAL action

Tags: java, oracle, oracle-ucm

I am trying to check in a document on Oracle Universal Content Management platform with `IdcClientManager` on Java.

I keep getting this error:

```
oracle.stellent.ridc.protocol.ServiceException: Content item 'ada' was not successfully checked in. The field 'Last Accessed' does not contain a valid date.
    at oracle.stellent.ridc.protocol.ServiceResponse.getResponseAsBinder(ServiceResponse.java:116)
    at oracle.stellent.ridc.protocol.ServiceResponse.getResponseAsBinder(ServiceResponse.java:92)
```

I tried several options including:

```
inputBinder.putLocal("xLastAccess","11/27/10 12:13 PM");
inputBinder.putLocal("xNoLatestRevisionDate","11/27/10 12:13 PM");
inputBinder.putLocal("xCT_LastAccessed","11/27/10 12:13 PM");
```

What field should I set and how should I set it to work around this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an explanation how to set up a default time value for check ins.

http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E14571_01/doc.1111/e10978/c10_content_tracker.htm#CSMRC1121

even though there is a lot of good information here, it did not really solve my problem.

Instead I checked the parameter key for the Last Accessed field on "Administration -> Admin Applets -> Configuration Manager -> Information Fields." and found out that it is CT_LastAccessed.

Later, upon debugging the outputBinder for checkout action, the actual key is xCT_LastAccessed.

To get the valid date format I used the DATE_FORMAT field in `oracle.stellent.ridc.model.impl.DataObjectEncodingUtils`.

then it works.